# How to call dynamic generated instance?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to generate a dynamic variable such as the following:

```
varnum = rand(100000)
value = 5
instance_variable_set("@v" + varnum.to_s, value)
```

Now, in IRB, if the varnum returned 345 - you can deduce that the variable generated is @v345

However, running the code in a script - how would you be able to call it? Is there a way to patch a variable with something like @v + varnum.to_s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you ever wanted to access the variable again, you'd have to do one of two things:

- Keep an array of all the instance variables that you dynamically generate
- Use `Object#instance_variables` to get a list of instance variables, and take out only those that start with `v`.

To access a variable once you still have it's value, use this:

```
instance_variable_get("@v#{varnum.to_s}")
```

There is a deeper problem here though. You should *never*, *ever*, **ever** dynamically generate instance variables. If you need to access data through a random number as a part of an object, have one instance variable, say `@vs`, which is a hash mapping random numbers to your value.

Answer (score 4):

Without assigning the variable to anything, unfortunately there isnt an exact way of how you can obtain it. if that is the case you can simply use `instance_variable_get`

If you are using this technique only once you can perhaps obtain it via some indirect means. I.e giving it a special name... v being for the example

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :015 > instance_variables
 => ["@v48563", "@prompt"]
```

You can add a grep to this using a regex.

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :016 > instance_variables.grep(/@v/)
 => ["@v48563"]
```

Comment: Good answer. I still hold that doing this in the first place is a bad idea. +1.

Comment: I agree. But no harm in hacking away!

Comment: @sohaibbbhatti: Agreed! I like hacking!

Answer (score 1):

```
instance_variable_get("@v" + varnum.to_s)
```

This calls the defined instance variable